# Join tables that might not have records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I have two tables, `tableA` which has a list of records and `tableB` which has restrictions (if any). How can I join the tables that will essentially be an `inner join` if there are records in `tableB` or no join if `tableB` is empty?

ie:

```
tableA
id | name 
1 | val1
2 | val2

tableB (with restrictions)
id | name | userID
1 | val1 | 123

OR tableB (no restrictions)
id | name | userID
```

is this possible? My attempt below:

```
    SELECT a.*
    FROM tableA a
    INNER JOIN (CASE WHEN select 1 from tableB = 1 THEN tableB ELSE tableA END) b
    ON a.id = b.id
where userID = XXX
```

*EDIT*: There is a check on tableB

Comment: what is your database engine?

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: You are looking for an outer join

Comment: Isn't this just a left join, what am I missing?

Comment: It's not a left join because `tableB` might have no rows.. if it has no rows then the query fails

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question ... just use a left join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a left join

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b = ON a.id = b.id and b.userid = xxx
```

I'm not seeing any complexity beyond that at present - given the simplicity of the statement in the original question, I am wondering if you are putting WHERE predicates against the table B - if you are, they need to be in the ON clause of the join

Edited to include your where clause moved.

Comment: Ah yes.. there is tableB in the where clause!

Comment: Move that predicate to the join ON condition, otherwise the left join acts like an inner join inadvertently (unless you allow for null values)

Answer (score 2):

For empty rows, u can use same query for both restrictions.
I guess you are usign `SQL server`

Use left join to pull rows if table b is blank

```
select a.id,a.name 
    from tableA a left join tableB on a.id = b.id
```

Demo:

```
declare @tableA table (id int, name varchar(10))
insert into @tableA
select 1, 'name'
union all
select 2,'name1'
union all
select 3,'name2'

declare @tableb table (id int, name varchar(10))

select a.id,a.name 
from @tableA a left join @tableb b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I dont think this solves my problem.. I want to be able to pull in all from tableA if tableB is blank

Comment: This will not work. If TableB is empty this result set will be empty.

Comment: Check with left join

Comment: left join wont work because tableB is empty it wont pull any records

Comment: did u tried it, it will pull records from table a if table b is empty

Comment: Removing where clause from lef tjoin query will get results

Comment: @Hadrian Yes! Thank you.. so dumb of me

Comment: @Hadrian Am I being dense here? This: select a.id,a.name 
from tableA a inner join tableB on a.id = b.id
where b.id <>'' does not address the problem at all. The left join solution is good though.

Comment: @Error_2646 you right, i should only keep left join query, not inner join query really

Answer (score 1):

this will pull all records from `tableA` if `tableB` is empty and only matching records if it is not:

```
select a.id, a.name 
from tableA a
    join tableB on a.id = b.id
where exists (select 1 from tableB)
union all
select a.id, a.name 
from tableA a
where not exists (select 1 from tableB)
```